# Template Tags not supported in Stylesheets

Tags: python, html, css, django, django-templates

Suppose I create a stylesheet in Django in static files.
So everything else is working fine. Its just that when I use this line, it gives an error

```css
.PostProfilePic {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-image: url('{{ Profile.ProfilePic.url }}');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
}
```

Suppose there is a class name `PostProfilePic` and I want to use an image from the database as my background image. so how can we do it???

Error is on this line

```css
background-image: url('{{ Profile.ProfilePic.url }}');
```

It says `cannot resolve file`

And also when I use this style in my HTML page between the  tags as shown below then it works completely fine

```js
<style>
  .PostProfilePic {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-image: url('{{ Profile.ProfilePic.url }}');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
  }
</style>
```

While making a separate `.css` file creates trouble...Any Solutions on this??

Comment: You can’t access those variables in your stylesheet. I’d suggest writing that css inline in your template where you can access the variable or use javascript

Comment: Is the problem solved? Have you had a look at my answer?

Comment: Yes I included the styling which required {{ }} inside the template...and all other things in the stylesheet.

Comment: @KartikeyVaish If the answer helped in your problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `background-image: url('{{ Profile.ProfilePic.url }}');` in an external `.css` file will not work since django will not render the variables. Note that the `url` css function should satisy the following constraint

> The url() CSS function is used to include a file. The parameter is an absolute URL, a relative URL, or a data URI.

As such it will not display anything since this `'{{ Profile.ProfilePic.url }}'` doesn't resolve to anything.

The curly braces `{{`- `}}` can only render variables in templates, hence the reason why it works in your second attempt as it's an internal definition of `CSS` within the template.